# How can you encode a character using utf-8 in an html document and get the script to execute, not just print?

Tags: javascript, html

Im working with the below code just as a tester, and I want it to actually send out the alert when I load the html file. However, all I get is `<script> alert(1)` printed to my screen. How can I make this code execute instead of just printing?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<&#115;cript>
    alert(1)
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I am encoding this character to circumvent tag removal, so just replacing the s with an s won't solve my problem

Comment: Use `<meta charset="UTF-8">` for HTML5.

Comment: The browser thinks `&#115` is content, so it's rendered as text, so it isn't a tag the browser's parser knows not to do that.

Comment: I already tried including the charset tag and that didn't change anything

Comment: Don't change your question or future readers will be confused.

Comment: Change `&#115` to the letter `s`. Add to the question without changing it, but you'll have to explain why this is not the answer in order to proceed any further.

Comment: "I am encoding this character to circumvent tag removal..." You don't think they might have accounted for that sort of thing?

Comment: So who or what is doing the tag removal and why?

Answer (score 1):

The parsing order in the browser processes the HTML tags first to build the DOM structure and so your tag is invalid syntax to that process and would be handled as content. Encoding would not be handled in the parsing process because it is content related not DOM related.

A fuller explination of my summary answer can be found [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/#The_main_flow) or a graphical representation of the same information [here](http://arvindr21.github.io/howBrowserWorks/#/17). Both can be found by searching for "how browsers work".